# 20.04 LTS terminal not accepting input

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, tty

I have been trying to input into the terminal with the keyboard, however, it only shows a blinking white cursor. I have tried CTRL+ALT+F3 to go into tty. Again, I cannot input any characters into this either. I have tried various other terminal programs and reinstalled gnome-terminal. Any other suggestions I can try? VSCode terminals do not work either.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxDqb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recently updated to angular 14, with this it included an autocomplete feature that appended a line to my .bashrc file

`# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.`

`source <(ng completion script)`

because I had angular installed through npx and not globally the ng command was not available, so a solution was to comment out the line or install angular globally with:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`